# Postgres exclusion constraint on insert/update

Tags: postgresql, triggers, constraints, exclusion-constraint

I have a table defined like so

```
                               Table "public.foo"
  Column  |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |               Default               
----------+---------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------
 foo_id   | integer |           | not null | nextval('foo_foo_id_seq'::regclass)
 bar_id   | integer |           |          | 
 approved | boolean |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "foo_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (foo_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "foo_bar_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (bar_id) REFERENCES bar(bar_id)
```

How would I define an exclusion constraint, such that only one row of `foo` with a specific `bar_id` would be able to set `approved` to true?

For example with the following data:

```
 foo_id | bar_id | approved 
--------+--------+----------
      1 |      1 | t
      2 |      1 | 
      3 |      2 | 
(3 rows)
```

I would be able to set `approved` to row 3 to true, because no other row with `foo_id` 3 has true for approved.

However updating row 2 's `approved` to true would fail, because row 1 also has `foo_id` 1 and is already approved.

Comment: I think in your description you are mixing foo_id and bar_id - a consequence of obfuscating column names

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an exclusion constraint, a filtered unique index will do:

```
create unique index only_one_approved_bar 
   on foo (bar_id)
   where approved;
```

I would also recommend to define `approved` as `not null`. Boolean columns that allow `null` values are typically a source of constant confusion.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ALTER TABLE public.foo
ADD CONSTRAINT uniq_approved UNIQUE (bar_id, approved)
```

or you can create unique index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniq_approved ON public.foo
USING btree (bar_id, approved)
WHERE approved
```

Comment: That won't allow multiple rows with approved = false

Comment: added to answer example with unique index and where. It will work only for rows where approved is true